# Adding special text, signs, symbols, and marks, to LilyPond scores

Tags: notation, lilypond, repeats, rests

What is the best way to add special text, signs, symbols, and marks for multi-measure rests, rehearsal marks, segno, and coda symbols, in LilyPond code?

[image: Examples of multi-measure rest, rehearsal mark in a box, segno, dal segno al coda, and coda symbols.]

Answer (score 5):

For compressed multi-measure rests, use `\compressMMRests { ... }`.

However, the default is set to use multiple (archaic) rest symbols for rests that are 10 measures or less.  To get a small number of rest to compress (like in your image), you will need an override:

```
\override MultiMeasureRest.expand-limit = #1
\compressMMRests {R1*4}
```

see: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/writing-parts#compressing-empty-measures

---

To write rehearsal marks, just use `\mark\default`, but to get letters in boxes you will need to set the rehearsal mark format:

```
\set Score.rehearsalMarkFormatter = #format-mark-box-letters
\mark\default
```

see: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/bars.en.html#rehearsal-marks

---

The segno and coda (symbols) can simply be entered with `\segno` and `\coda`.

And to get "D.S. al coda", "To Coda", etc. you can enter them as markups: `...^\markup {\bold "D.S. al Coda"}`.

But in the new versions of LilyPond (v2.23 and later) there is a way to encode these long repeat structures so that the symbols appear automatically:

```
s1 |
\repeat segno 2 {
    s1 |
    \alternative {
        \volta 1 {
            s1 |
        }
    }
}
\section \sectionLabel "Coda"
s1 |
\bar "|."
```

see: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/long-repeats#segno-repeat-structure